# Can I feed a 5V boost converter with 4xNiMH cells?

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, nimh

The [spec page](https://www.pololu.com/product/791) of my DC-DC boost converter (couldn't find a datasheet) says ”the input voltage should be kept below the output voltage”. And 4x the nominal 1.2V from an NiMH cell is below my 5V output voltage. But a fully charged NiMH battery starts [at around 1.4V](https://na.industrial.panasonic.com/sites/default/pidsa/files/nimh_batteries_series_datasheets_merged_11.24.14.pdf) for a short time, for a total 5.6V.

Is this something I need to worry about in practice? It's a relatively high current application (driving a couple of dozen LEDs), so I'd like the extra capacity/current draw from four cells.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is quite simple:

Consider a boost architecture:

[image: Boost architecture]

If Vin is above the programmed Vout, then D1 will forward bias, feeding Vin to Vout. The loop will attempt to compensate by reducing output drive, but it will be powerless and you will simply dump Vin (minus a diode drop) across the load.

What will happen to loop stablity or the controller is device dependent.

So the answer is - No, keep Vin below Vout.

[Update]

I would be far more concerned about loop stability than the small amount of time that Vin would be above Vout.

Comment: But with a max of 5.6V in, the output would likely go just a bit above 5V (Which the OP doesn't seem to care about.)  It doesn't violate the abs max input of 2X Vout, so if there are no control loop or other funny effects it's probably OK.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to says "Once the input exceeds the output set point, the output voltage will rise with the input voltage since the input is connected to the output through an inductor and a diode."

If you don't mind a little higher output voltage, it won't matter.

But why don't you just use the 4 cells in parallel (or rather 2 times 2, to meet minimum input voltage)? This increases the capacity and current, and also circumvents the issue alltogether

Comment: Good point about putting the cells in parallel—but it would make my design quite a bit harder mechanically. The batteries need to sit inside a tube that forms the shaft of a juggling club.

Comment: The lower the input-output voltage difference the more efficient the booster can be. Diode D1 will drop ~0.4V, so even with fully charged cells you shouldn't get more than 5.2V under load.